# Create 3 Views blocks that display 1st, 2nd, and 3rd most recently created nodes

Tags: views, nodes, theming

How can you create **three View blocks** such that (based on a particular **field value** or **taxonomy category** or just **content type**) the **first block** displays the most **recently CREATED** (not updated) node, the **second** displays the **second most recently created** node, and the **third** displays the **third most recently created** node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the 3 views blocks with your filters and order by **created**. Then change the *Pager* to *Display a specified number of items*.

For 1st block update the *settings* (it should say displaying X items) then update the *Items to display* to 1 and the *offset* to 0.

For the 2nd block do the same but change the *offset* to 1 and then for the third block set the *offset* to 2.

Untested but on a quick check of the options, this should give you what you are after.

Paul

Comment: thanks, this seems workable. I'll work with it and let you know how it goes.